# ¿Cómo pasar registros de un Datagridview con columnas repetidas a otro DatagridView?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Tengo un `DatagridView` cargado con datos de una bbdd.

Existe una columna llamada `formulaciones` la cual contiene datos numéricos. Estos datos numéricos algunas veces se repiten, lo que me interesa es como pasar toda la fila de esas columnas repetidas a otro `DatagridView`

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Yo personalmente no entiendo tu problema. Podrías [edit] la pregunta y añadir un ejemplo de los datos que tienes y como debería quedar el segundo `DatagridView`?

Comment: Yo te diría que la mejor opción es manejarlo desde la consulta a la base de datos. Una consulta tiene valores no duplicados y rellena un Datagrid y la otra consulta contiene los duplicados y rellena el segundo Datagrid.

Comment: El otro datagrid esta en el mismo formulario?

Comment: @Manny el datagridview si esta en el mismo formulario

Comment: @MarcosJesusMendoza las columnas estan definidas en el datagrid o lo estas cargando con datasource?

Comment: @MarcosJesusMendoza puse mi respuesta, como no proporcionaste mas informacion en que evento lo utilizarias, yo utilize el evento CellDoubleClick.

Comment: @Manny  el datagridview 1 esta cargado con datasource mientras que el datagridview dos no esta cargado con datasoruece, este se encuentra vacio

Answer (score 0):

En el evento double click de tu datagrid donde cargas los datos.
Ojo, tu datagrid2 debe de contener la cantidad de columnas que quieres pasar del grid1 al grid2

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            string fol;

            fol = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();//obtenemos el string con el que vamos a comparar, donde 0 es sera el numero de tu columna formulaciones
          //mediante el uso de linq obtenemos un array de repetidos donde 0 es el numero de tu columna
            string[] repetidos = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells[0].Value)).ToArray();
            if(repetidos.Length > 0)//si el array tiene mas de 1 item, entonces hay repetidos
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < repetidos.Length; )//recorremos el array
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)//recorremo el datagrid
                    {
                        if (fol == repetidos[i])
                        {
                            //agregamos un nuevo row al datagrid2 mediante un objeto y le pasamos los datos de la fila, donde 0 es la columna formulaciones y 1,2,3,4 etc seran todas tus columnas que contenga esa fila
                            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new object[]
                        {
                        dataGridView1[0,dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value, dataGridView1[1,dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value

                        }
                    );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //puedes hacer otra cosa
                              MessageBox.Show("El numero seleccionado no tiene repetidos");
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Prueba y comentas.